# How to prevent Outlook for Android from formatting number into a link

Tags: android, html, email, outlook

I've got problem, creating email template. When email has a number with 5 or more characters, outlook formats it in a link. I tried to use `<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no"/>` but have got no result.

Answer (score 0):

Add `<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">` to your document `<head>`.

Comment: I don't know what the deal is with Outlook specifically, but a potential workaround is to wrap the number in an anchor tag yourself so that you can manually format it, hopefully preventing Outlook from parsing it. For example, `<a style="pointer-events: none; text-decoration: none">12345</a>`.

Comment: This solution was ok for me on android email client